# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _Direct3DCreate9Ex@8 referenced in function "protected: XYX()"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, linker, winapi

I am getting the following LINK error while compiling my C++ solution:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _Direct3DCreate9Ex@8
>   referenced in function "protected: XYX()

The symbol "Direct3DCreate9Ex' is defined in "ddraw.h" header file found in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include".   And verified that the header file "ddraw.h" is present in this location. Also I have included this path in VS settings "Tools-->Options-->VC++ Directories -> Includes".

But still I am getting the link error as "**error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _Direct3DCreate9Ex@8 referenced in function "protected: XYX()**" ".

Can anyone kindly help me in getting rid of this link error while compiling my C++ solution. 
I am using VS 2008 on 64 bit Win7.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: a link error has not much to do with include files and compiler options. Go to linker options instead and add ddraw.lib or so as input.

Comment: I have never dealt with linker options. Can you kindly let me know how & where should one go to set the linker options. Any pointers would be helpful for me :)

Comment: everything is under Project Properties->Linker. Documentation can be found on msdn, google, stackoverflow, ....

Comment: ok i will search for it thanks for pointing :)

Comment: Yes, d3d9.lib does exist in Linker options. And the error I am getting does is because of d3d9 only as "Direct3DCreate9Ex" is a part of ddraw.h

Comment: Also I have included dxguid.lib in the linker options

Answer (score 3):

Based on reference page for [Direct3DCreate9Ex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb219676%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you need to link with `D3D9.lib`.

Comment: S I have added the path to DirectX Lib folder  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (February 2010)\Lib\x64"  in the VS settings: "Tools-->Options-->VC++ Directories-> Library"  which has "d3d9.lib. But still :(

Comment: @codeLover, I am sorry but I do not use IDEs so I don't know if you want to have done is correct. But note that just because you are on a 64-bit machine does not necessarily mean you are building a 64-bit executable, it is possible to build 32-bit binaries.

Comment: you have to specify d3d9.lib in Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies

Comment: Yes, d3d9.lib does exist in Linker options. And the error I am getting does is because of d3d9 only as "Direct3DCreate9Ex" is a part of ddraw.h

Comment: Also I have included dxguid.lib in the linker options.

Comment: you are sure you're not mixing 32bit and 64 bit as hmjd already pointed out? Another possibility is a mismatch between the SDK header ddraw and your installed version of directX. Direct3DCreate9Ex is normally in D3D9.h so I would use that instead of ddraw.h